# How to output CMB2 select options from repeated groups select elements?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, select

I've searched in previous posted questions but I can't find something similar (but if it's already posted, please let me know). 
I've got the following repeated group of fields, with a select in it:

```
$social_group_field_id = $social_options->add_field(array(
'id' => $prefix . 'social_network', 
'type' => 'group',
'description' => esc_html__('Add items and insert the URLs of your social media pages', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
'options' => array(
    'group_title' => esc_html__('Social media {#}', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
    'add_button' => esc_html__('Add social media', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
    'remove_button' => esc_html__('Remove social media', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
    'sortable' => true,
    'closed' => true, // true to have the groups closed by default
    'remove_confirm' => esc_html__( 'Are you sure you want to remove?', 'my-theme-text-domain' ),
),
));
$social_options->add_group_field($social_group_field_id, array(
'id' => $prefix . 'social_media_select',
'name' => esc_html__('Choose social media', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
'description' => esc_html__('Choose the social media include', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
'type' => 'select',
'show_option_none' => true,
'default' => 'custom',
'options_cb' => 'socialmedia_options',
));
$social_options->add_group_field($social_group_field_id, array(
'id' => $prefix . 'social_media_url',
'name' => esc_html__('URL', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
'description' => esc_html__('Write your URL for the social media selected above', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
'type' => 'text_url',));
```

What I'm trying to do is to offer a selection of social media to choose, with a select with a list of the main social media networks and a input text field to write the associated profile URL.
The select options comes from an array inside an external "socialmedia_options" function retrieved by the options_cb:

```
function socialmedia_options() {
return array(
...
    'name-of the social' => __('Name of the social', 'my-theme-text-domain'),
...
);}
```

Now I'd like to output a list of links, cycling the results based on the repeated group created and the relative selected options in it.

Is it possible, or it's the wrong strategy?